# python keep 60 right most bits out of 64 bits - type error

Tags: python, bit-manipulation, python-3.5

I have 64 bits integer and I would like to keep right most 60 bits and discard most significant 4 bits. I am using python 3.5.4. Any advice on this problem?

My code is generating type error:

```
def remove_padding(num):
    num &= num >> 4
    return num

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for >>: 'float' and 'int'
```

Comment: What is `num`? Are you *sure* it's an integer?

Comment: It is 64 digits integer. I think Python 3.5 does not recognize it as integer.

Comment: Python should support that, so it's confusing as to why that's the case.

Comment: @tadman Given 64 bits integer, I did bit operation n &= n >> 4. Will it be a problem?

Comment: It worked when I tested it on Python 3, so should for you, but this depends on the number *actually* being an integer and not a float for some reason.

Comment: How do you call the function? As it stands it's just not clear what actual code produced the exception (useful link [mcve]).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to **keep** the 60 *least* significant bits, right? By rightshifting you would keep the 60 *most* significant bits.

```
...6....'....5....'....4....'....3....'....2....'....1....'....0
DDDDKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK   Input
0000KKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK   Output
```

`D` = Discard, `K` = Keep

In this case, you just need to `And` your input with hexadecimal `0FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF`:

```
num &= 0x0FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
```